# The public that gathered on 19 December at the Maryinsky Theatre - is "the public" used wrongly here?

Tags: word-usage, definite-articles

> **The public** that gathered on 19 December, 1890, at the Maryinsky Theatre in Saint Petersburg gave Tchaikovsky's *The Queen Of Spades* a very warm reception. ([source](http://www.usc.edu/dept/polish_music/news/jan05.html))

I'm investigating the senses of the term **[the public](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/public?searchDictCode=all)** and the reasons why it seems to always take the definite article or other determiner, such as the possessive pronoun **my**. I got interested after reading [this question at ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40732/the-public-vs-public).

I have the hunch that the use of **the public** in the quoted sentence is wrong somehow, and **the members of the public** would've been a better choice. It seems to me that **the public** is too broad a concept in English to stand for "the group of people gathered in a particular place at a particular time".

Am I right? To a native speaker, would the mention of **the public** seem out of place in the specific situation described in the sentence?

(Such use is okay in Russian)

Comment: Usually ***the public*** refers to ***all people collectively***, so the cited usage is relatively uncommon, but that doesn't make it *wrong*. [*Although early modern French speakers used 'public' as a noun to refer to an assembly or audience – like **the 'public' that gathered physically in a playhouse** or the virtual 'public' that read a book – seminary directors used 'public' as an adjective*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FfDRAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&dq=%22the+public+that+gathered%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UMl5VJbdOIaxaZTNAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20public%20that%20gathered%22&f=false)

Comment: This is a matter of style, and as such can be argued either way.

Comment: The phrase appears in a newsletter by the Polish Music Center, and I suspect perhaps the writer is a native Polish speaker. In Polish (as in many other European languages), the word for an audience (the assembled spectators or listeners at a public event, like a play or an opera) is _publika_, which could lead to overuse of the word _public_ in this sense in English where _audience_ would be more natural.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I agree. The same is true for the Russian language: "public" as "audience". The matter is, I was pondering on whether the use of **the public** is correct [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40732/the-public-vs-public), and looking for examples.

Comment: @Janus: There are quite a few written instances of the exact text [*"the public that gathered"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+public+that+gathered%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Seeing the first one here it initially looked *slightly* odd to me simply because it's uncommon (reflected in the fact that more than one of those citations has "scare quotes" around the word ***public***). But after seeing it used a few times the "strangeness" of unfamiliarity rapidly wears off - for me, at least.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no problem with “the public that gathered [at/around]…” in general, and most of the cases in your link seem just fine to me. Where this example loses me is that the ‘public’ it refers to is not just a randomly gathering group of people in a public situation, but clearly an organised _audience_ for a performance in a theatre. That use jars with me as more awkward than just uncommon or antiquated.

Comment: @Janus: I think *audience* in your first comment (and even more so ***organised** audience* in the second) seem to add connotations that aren't necessarily present in the excerpt as cited (and lose connotations that *are* in the original). To me it's just an unusual (antiquated?) single-word usage referring to ***part** of 'the public'*. I'd sooner replace it with *"those members of the public"* rather than *audience*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several of the comments have pointed out, the correct English word is "audience". Many Western and Eastern European languages use in this sense the equivalent of French publique, German Publikum, but English goes its own way.

Have a look at this: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/audience (under "translations").

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, but it makes me picture the people standing around *outside* the theater. (Especially because it says "gathered... *at*") The *audience* would specifically refer to those who were inside watching the show.